# How to revert a Django model instance after making some changes?

Tags: django

Suppose I have a Django model as follows:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Somewhere I have an instance p, and I make some changes to it.

```
p.first_name = 'new first name'
```

Due to some reason, I wish to revert all the changes I made to this instance. One way I can think of reverting is as follows:

```
p = Person.objects.get(pk=p.pk)
```

The above code depends upon the Model class name. Is there any simpler model independent way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an instance p,

```
p = p.__class__._default_manager.get(pk=p.pk)
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanx, I am still wondering if there is a well defined method for this. Is it not a general use case in Django?

Comment: @Shailesh: `p` is just a normal Python object like any other once you have retrieved it from the database. In order to simply be able to "revert" the changes you've made to the object, the old values need to be stored inside that object (or have the object provide a method which does the code spulec gave you behind the scenes). I've never had to do this as far as I can remember. What do you want it for? Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: @Deniz I was basically writing some unit tests (using py.test). In the tests, I was playing with the values of attributes of p, then doing some tests on p, then reverting p back to the original values i had. May be this isn't a common enough scenario requiring special support from Django.

Comment: @Shailesh Kumar: If this is for unit tests, you could simply not call `save()` and rely on setup methods to get the data from the database each time. Thus, between tests you can assume that the old values will be on your object.